# Azure - Websocket only works correctly when server is run in the browser

Tags: azure, websocket

I'm working on an app in Azure. Server is supposed to get the key for the azure map from the key vault. The client uses the websocket to get the key from the server. Everything works fine when I first run the server in the browser (quite stupidly). It just shows: Upgrade Required (which it is supposed to show). After that the client connects to the server just fine. I can even close the tab with the server after that and everything works.

But without this strange action websocket gives "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302".

I don't really understand what's happening. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Have you enabled websocket option in Azure Portal  =>Your Web App =>  Configuration => General Settings

Comment: websocket is enabled

Comment: Have you checked the [CORS Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in authorization. The backend wanted to get user authorization behind the scenes. It couldn't get it from the frontend side obviously. So I just removed authorization request from the backend side. And it all started to work.